Add inner-tag inside a tag precedently assigned with a conditional logic in a XSLT
I'm working on a xslt that parse a String Test (txt inside <root></root>) and i want that:
<xsl:if test="starts-with(., ' 61')">
 <xsl:variable name="IBAN" select="concat(substring(.,100,4),substring(.,52,23))" />
 <Stmt>
  <Acct>
   <Id>
    <IBAN><xsl:value-of select="$IBAN"/></IBAN>
   </Id>
  </Acct>
 </Stmt>
</xsl:if>

but precedenlty i has already created this tag in another if:
the question is simply: How insert a tag in a precedelty father-tag?
my code is this:
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:variable name="parts" select="str:split(root, ' RH')"/>
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="$parts">
                <xsl:variable name="part" select="concat(' RH', .)" />
                <xsl:variable name="lines" select="str:tokenize($part, '&#x0A;')"/>
                <Document>
                    <BkToCstmrStmt>
                        <GrpHdr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$lines">
                    <xsl:if test="starts-with(., ' RH')">
                        <Stmt>
                            <Id><xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring(., 20, 20)),'-1')"/></Id> <!-- perchè -1 possono esseci piu id? -->
                            <ElctrncSeqNb>1</ElctrncSeqNb> <!-- Progressivo di rendicontazione elettronica da verificare come si vuole fare-->
                            <CreDtTm><xsl:value-of select="concat($year, '-', $month, '-', $day, 'T', $hour, ':', $minute, ':', $second, 'Z')"/></CreDtTm>
                        </Stmt>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="starts-with(., ' 61')">
                        <xsl:variable name="IBAN" select="concat(substring(.,100,4),substring(.,52,23))" />
                        <Stmt>
                        <Acct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN><xsl:value-of select="$IBAN"/></IBAN>
                        </Id>
                        </Acct>
                        </Stmt>
                    </xsl:if>

                </xsl:for-each>
                </GrpHdr>
                </BkToCstmrStmt>
                </Document>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

now code inside second if overwrite first <STMT> in first if. i want only insert.
input xml:
<root>
 RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171
 610000001                  93001                  G0305101700000000004575EUR270524C000000000000,00IT44
 620000001001270524270524D000000000649,3450TE                ITDA00DPN145
 630000001001HAYS SRL/AVIS BUDGET ITALIA S.P.A./AR885265/2355070853/B2B/RCUR/OE5OA5200P4907R3
 640000001EUR270524C000000000000,00
 EF03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951171           0000001                              0000006
 RH03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349
 610000001                  93001                  Z0305101699000078389249USD270524C000000001320,97IT72
 640000001USD270524C000000001320,97
 EF03051CDSIA280524CM1490301951349           0000001                              0000004
</root>

i want this xml after trasformation:
<root>
  <Document>
    <BkToCstmrStmt>
      <GrpHdr>
        <Stmt>
          <Id>CM1490301951171-1</Id>
          <ElctrncSeqNb>1</ElctrncSeqNb>
          <CreDtTm>2024-05-28T12:08:29Z</CreDtTm>
          <Acct>
            <Id>
              <IBAN>IT44G0305101700000000004575</IBAN>
            </Id>
          </Acct>
        </Stmt>
      </GrpHdr>
    </BkToCstmrStmt>
  </Document>
</root>

but i obtain this:
 <root>
  <Document>
    <BkToCstmrStmt>
      <GrpHdr>
        <Stmt>
          <Id>CM1490301951171-1</Id>
          <ElctrncSeqNb>1</ElctrncSeqNb>
          <CreDtTm>2024-05-28T12:08:29Z</CreDtTm>
        </Stmt>
        <Stmt>
          <Acct>
            <Id>
              <IBAN>IT44G0305101700000000004575</IBAN>
            </Id>
          </Acct>
        </Stmt>
      </GrpHdr>
    </BkToCstmrStmt>
  </Document>
</root>

any tips for me?
Thanks
Regards

If you use an XSLT 1 processor why does your XSLT have xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no" which is only part of XSLT 2 and later.

Your question is not clear. Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of the input XML, your current XSLT and the expected output. --- Possible hint: use xsl:choose instead of xsl:if if you have 2 or more mutually exclusive options.

i changed question add an example

Your code is incomplete and errors out on undefined variables in:
<CreDtTm><xsl:value-of select="concat($year, '-', $month, '-', $day, 'T', $hour, ':', $minute, ':', $second, 'Z')"/></CreDtTm>

And AFAICT, your input should produce 3 Document elements, but your expected output shows only one.
This is not what a minimal example should be.

I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="parts" select="str:split(root, ' RH')"/>
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="$parts">
            <xsl:variable name="part" select="concat(' RH', .)" />
            <xsl:variable name="lines" select="str:tokenize($part, '&#x0A;')"/>
            <Document>
                <BkToCstmrStmt>
                    <GrpHdr>
                        <Stmt>
                            <Id>
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring($lines[1], 20, 20)),'-1')"/>
                            </Id> 
                            <ElctrncSeqNb>1</ElctrncSeqNb>
                            <CreDtTm>
                                <!-- ??? missing variables ??? -->
                            </CreDtTm>
                            <xsl:variable name="line61" select="$lines[starts-with(., ' 61')]"/>
                            <xsl:if test="$line61">
                                <Acct>
                                    <Id>
                                        <IBAN>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($line61, 100, 4),substring($line61, 52, 23))"/>
                                        </IBAN>
                                    </Id>
                                </Acct>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </Stmt>
                    </GrpHdr>
                </BkToCstmrStmt>
            </Document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

With your input example, this returns:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Document>
    <BkToCstmrStmt>
      <GrpHdr>
        <Stmt>
          <Id>-1</Id>
          <ElctrncSeqNb>1</ElctrncSeqNb>
          <CreDtTm/>
        </Stmt>
      </GrpHdr>
    </BkToCstmrStmt>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <BkToCstmrStmt>
      <GrpHdr>
        <Stmt>
          <Id>CM1490301951171-1</Id>
          <ElctrncSeqNb>1</ElctrncSeqNb>
          <CreDtTm/>
          <Acct>
            <Id>
              <IBAN>IT44G0305101700000000004575</IBAN>
            </Id>
          </Acct>
        </Stmt>
      </GrpHdr>
    </BkToCstmrStmt>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <BkToCstmrStmt>
      <GrpHdr>
        <Stmt>
          <Id>CM1490301951349-1</Id>
          <ElctrncSeqNb>1</ElctrncSeqNb>
          <CreDtTm/>
          <Acct>
            <Id>
              <IBAN>IT72Z0305101699000078389249</IBAN>
            </Id>
          </Acct>
        </Stmt>
      </GrpHdr>
    </BkToCstmrStmt>
  </Document>
</root>

